# how to monitor all network traffic on android device?

Tags: android, networking

I want to monitor all the network traffic on android device.
I know about the 'wireshark' version that run on android.

But i wander if there is some way to do it using some debug tool - or maybe with android studio that will show all the network traffic and will tell me what network traffic belong to what process.

I check the 'android device monitor' and there is 'network statistic' there but it really don't give nothing.

Is there any other way to do it ?